# PostgreSQL selecting rows from table with specified condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL database. I have a table `course(id, c_name)` and  want to retrieve `id`s having enrolled to more than one courses

`I am trying following query but it doesn't return any record.

`SELECT id
FROM sub
where c_name = 'comp'
and c_name = 'maths'`

Any help in this regard?

Comment: This is SQL 101 stuff. You really need to start with something like http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

```
select id, count(distinct c_name) 
from course 
group by id 
having count(distinct c_name) > 1
```

Comment: Thanks Owen. I have tried it and worked perfectly as i want. It was very useful for me.